# Batik - Modify and saving of SVG results in not well formed XML

Tags: java, svg, batik

I'm trying to edit an existing SVG and save it afterwards using Batik (I need different formats and DOM-Manipulation).

What I do:

- Adobe Illustrator Source File (CS 4.0) saved as SVG 1.0 with all Glyphs (two embedded Fonts)
- Loaded with Batik (using SAXSVGDocumentFactory, source below)
- DOM-Modifications (even without modifications the problem occurs)
- Saving using SVGTranscoder

After transcoding I get a new SVG-File, which is filled with XML, but is not able to render properly in Firefox or Illustrator.

In Firefox I get the message that the XML is not well formed e.g.,

```
<glyph horiz-adv-x="249" unicode=""/>
```

My Code:

```
///////////////
// Load Template File (with embedded Fonts)
///////////////
File file = new File(SVGFilePath);
FileInputStream svgInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);

////////////////////
// Load SVG into DOM-Tree
////////////////////
String parser = XMLResourceDescriptor.getXMLParserClassName();
SAXSVGDocumentFactory factory = new SAXSVGDocumentFactory(parser);
Document doc = factory.createDocument(parser, svgInputStream);

//...

///////////////////////
// Generate Output File
///////////////////////
String savepath = "test.svg";
byte[] fileData = transcodeToSVG(doc);
FileOutputStream fileSave = new FileOutputStream(savepath);
fileSave.write(fileData);
fileSave.close();
```

My Transcoding Code:

```
public byte[] transcodeToSVG(Document doc) throws TranscoderException {

    try {
        //Determine output type:
        SVGTranscoder t = new SVGTranscoder();

        //Set transcoder input/output
        TranscoderInput input = new TranscoderInput(doc);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytestream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter ostream = new OutputStreamWriter(bytestream);
        TranscoderOutput output = new TranscoderOutput(ostream);

        //Perform transcoding
        t.transcode(input, output);
        ostream.flush();
        ostream.close();

        return bytestream.toByteArray();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: I edited this question and apparently that (unintentionally) removed the character that was in `unicode=""`. I don't know if it will appear in this comment. I tried to edit it back into the question, but that didn't work. Apparently the document contained the Unicode noncharacter U+FFFF.

Comment: One thing I can suggest is to run both the source and output XML files through [xmllint](http://xmlsoft.org/xmllint.html) and see exactly what problems there are before and after. If you're on a Unix-y system you may already have xmllint or be able to install it via your package manager. It is also available as a package for Cygwin on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

David Conrads hint with the Unicode character lead me to the solution:

I was missing the right encoding of the file.

After changing

```
OutputStreamWriter ostream = new OutputStreamWriter(bytestream);
```

to

```
OutputStreamWriter ostream = new OutputStreamWriter(bytestream, "UTF-8");
```

it works well.